# C++ Compiling error in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation

I got error messages when compile, even I tried to add libstdc++.dylib into my project. May I know what I can do further to fix it?

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
"std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
  __GLOBAL__I_a in group.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in image.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in orthographic_camera.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in raycast.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in scene_parser.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in sphere.o
"std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
  __GLOBAL__I_a in group.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in image.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in orthographic_camera.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in raycast.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in scene_parser.o
  __GLOBAL__I_a in sphere.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: are you using third party libraries? are these .o files from that library?

Comment: I'm not sure. I imported those o.file directly. How can I know which third party libraries I am using?